# UIBezierPath with color gradient

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I've got an question about UIBezierPath.

For example I've got this path:

[image]

Now I want to have a color gradient from white to red. From left to right.

Here is my code:

```
UIBezierPath *bezierPath;
bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:_center radius:_radius startAngle:((4 * angle)) endAngle:(((20) * angle)) clockwise:YES];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:_center];
[bezierPath closePath];
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:0/sectors saturation:1. brightness:1. alpha:1];
[color setFill];
[color setStroke];
[bezierPath fill];
[bezierPath stroke];
```

Can anyone help me?

Edit 1:

I have this color wheel:

[image]

```
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath;

for ( int i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
    bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:_center radius:_radius startAngle:((i * angle)) endAngle:(((i + 1) * angle)) clockwise:YES];

    [bezierPath addLineToPoint:_center];
    [bezierPath closePath];
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:i/sectors saturation:1. brightness:1. alpha:1];
    [color setFill];
    [color setStroke];
    [bezierPath fill];
    [bezierPath stroke];
}
```

but I want this: (With the white Gradient)

[image]

Comment: Do you need it as an image or as a drawing? If an image/view is acceptable, have you considered adding a radial gradient: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494063/ios-transparent-radial-gradient-layer-mask

Comment: First, use `CGContextAddArc` instead of `UIBezierPath`. This will make your drawing more precise. Second, you may want to draw few white circles in the center with different radius (decresing, and alpha incresing) to get nice white center.

Comment: I need it as a drawing.But thanks!

Comment: @OlegShanyuk thank you, but I don't know how this works

Comment: When getting closer to the center, you need to either change the brightness or change the alpha while using a white background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give it a try :)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat arcStep = (M_PI *2) / 360; // M_PI*2 is equivalent of full cirle
    BOOL clocklwise = NO;
    CGFloat x = CGRectGetWidth(rect) / 2; // circle's center
    CGFloat y = CGRectGetHeight(rect) / 2; // circle's center
    CGFloat radius = MIN(x, y) / 2;
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // draw colorful circle
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, radius*2);
    for (CGFloat i = 0; i < 360; i+=1)
    {
        UIColor* c = [UIColor colorWithHue:i/360 saturation:1. brightness:1. alpha:1];

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, c.CGColor);

        CGFloat startAngle = i * arcStep;
        CGFloat endAngle = startAngle + arcStep + 0.02;

        CGContextAddArc(ctx, x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, clocklwise);
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    }
    // drawing circles then, you might want few of them - smaller radius and less alpha with each step
    UIColor* c = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent: 0.03];
    for (CGFloat fillRadius = radius/2; fillRadius > 0; fillRadius -= 1.f)
    {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, fillRadius*2);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, c.CGColor);
        CGContextAddArc(ctx, x, y, fillRadius, 0, M_PI * 2, clocklwise);
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is 'ctx' ? Atm I'm doing it this way:     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height), YES, 0.0); and so on. And what is with x/y?

Comment: x, y - this is your's circle center; ctx - this is your graphics context

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a totally beginner in graphics. How can add this to my view? My old code was in the drawRect method of a subclass from UIView. How I handle this?

Comment: Ok, you can do that in the `drawRect:` as well, let's update example one more time...

Comment: @DanielChristoph just try to copypaste

Comment: Well, it looks pretty nice. Thank you very much. But there is one little disturbing thing. Look at this link: http://imgur.com/8NDHsGG . Any idea ? I tried to look at the API, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: @DanielChristoph yup, too accurate math - doesn't overlap while drawing circle segments :) Fixed the example

Answer (score 3):

Use `CAGradientLayer` and mask it using `CAShapeLayer` Something like this

```
- (void)addCircle{
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer new];
    shapeLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectInset(CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100), 4, 4)].CGPath;
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    shapeLayer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    shapeLayer.shouldRasterize = NO;


    CAGradientLayer *_gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    _gradientLayer.frame =self.view.bounds;
    _gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 1);
    _gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0);
    _gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor];

    //Add gradient layer to view
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:_gradientLayer];
    _gradientLayer.mask = shapeLayer;
}
```

Above method will add a triangle may be you need to change start and end points. Also you can change gradient values to whatever you need.

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/)

[CAGradientLayer Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/90488/calayer-in-ios-with-swift-10-examples)

**Update** After update its more clear that its not triangle you want, but what you need is possible with `CAGradientLayer` and `CAShapeLayer`, you need to follow same approach where you can add gradient with different colors and locations (stops)(if you are adding locations then make sure locations and colors are equal) and then mask it with `CAShapeLayer` which was circle.

Comment: I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: where you are getting xc_bad_access?

Comment: I added my answer, copy paste this method and call this method from viewDidAppear or anywhere you need, it will add

Comment: see my edited question. Can I get this with your solution?

Comment: So its not triangle its full circle , yes you an do this with CAGradientLayer, drawing circle is not an issue just create a circle with CAShapeLayer and mask gradient layer, to create that gradient add all your colors and use locations as well.

Comment: Yeah it's a full circle, I thought that may not be a problem. :-) Sorry for that. Thanks for you answer, I'll try it out!

Answer (score 2):

Another take on Oleg's answer regarding the saturation (white gradient) that I find more pleasing, and in Swift (3).

You can add steps to the gradient if you want a bigger white circle (ex a 2nd white step at 0.2)

```
import UIKit

class HSView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let arcStep = 2 * CGFloat.pi / 360
        let isClockwise = false
        let x = rect.width / 2
        let y = rect.height / 2
        let radius = min(x, y) / 2
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        ctx?.setLineWidth(2 * radius)

        for i in 0..<360 {
            let color = UIColor(hue: CGFloat(i)/360, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
            let startAngle = CGFloat(i) * arcStep
            let endAngle = startAngle + arcStep + 0.02

            ctx?.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)
            ctx?.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: isClockwise)
            ctx?.strokePath()
        }

        let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: UIColor.white.cgColor.colorSpace,
                                  colors: [
                                    UIColor.white.cgColor,
                                    UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor,
                                    ] as CFArray,
                                  locations: [
                                    0,
                                    1,
            ]
        )
        ctx?.drawRadialGradient(gradient!, startCenter: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), startRadius: 0, endCenter: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), endRadius: 2 * radius, options: .drawsAfterEndLocation)
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
    //// General Declarations
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


//// Shadow Declarations
NSShadow* shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
[shadow setShadowColor: UIColor.whiteColor];
[shadow setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(2.1, -4.1)];
[shadow setShadowBlurRadius: 5];

//// Bezier Drawing
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[UIColor.blackColor setStroke];
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1;
[bezierPath stroke];


//// Bezier 2 Drawing
UIBezierPath* bezier2Path = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[bezier2Path moveToPoint: CGPointMake(170.5, 59.5)];
[bezier2Path addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(170.5, 71.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(173.5, 65.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(170.5, 71.5)];
[bezier2Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(155.5, 57.5)];
[bezier2Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(170.5, 59.5)];
[UIColor.redColor setFill];
[bezier2Path fill];

////// Bezier 2 Inner Shadow
CGContextSaveGState(context);
UIRectClip(bezier2Path.bounds);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeZero, 0, NULL);

CGContextSetAlpha(context, CGColorGetAlpha([shadow.shadowColor CGColor]));
CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, NULL);
{
    UIColor* opaqueShadow = [shadow.shadowColor colorWithAlphaComponent: 1];
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, shadow.shadowOffset, shadow.shadowBlurRadius, [opaqueShadow CGColor]);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceOut);
    CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, NULL);

    [opaqueShadow setFill];
    [bezier2Path fill];

    CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context);
}
CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

and the result will be:
[image]

Comment: you need to place the above code in drawRect method in an UIView.m file and make that as the file owner to your uiview

Answer (score 0):

You will archive it by using QuartsCore. If you want get image with your figure, you can call UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(), if you want draw it on UIView you should overload method - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect of UIView.
You can add path to context, and use it for [clipping](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClip) context (Don't forget save the context state before). After you can draw the [gradient](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextDrawLinearGradient). The gradient will be clipped by path.

You will get something like this:

```
CGPathRef path = [bezierPath CGPath];
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextClip(context);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor, nil];
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors( colorSpace, (CFArrayRef)colors, NULL);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
colorSpace = NULL;

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0), CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0), kNilOptions);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```