# How to fill a bezier path with gradient color

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, core-graphics, draw

I have a `UIBezierPath` inside my custom `UIView draw(_ rect: CGRect)` function. I would like to fill the path with a gradient color. Please can anybody guide me how can I do that.

I need to fill the clip with a gradient color and then stroke the path with black color.

There are some posts in SO which does not solve the problem. For example [Swift: Gradient along a bezier path (using CALayers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931076/swift-gradient-along-a-bezier-path-using-calayers) this post guides how to draw on a layer in `UIView` but not in a `UIBezierPath`.

**NB: I am working on Swift-3**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Gradient along a bezier path (using CALayers)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931076/swift-gradient-along-a-bezier-path-using-calayers)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074539/programmatically-create-a-uiview-with-color-gradient

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov I have already explored the thread, there is nothing on filling a UIBazierPath with gradient. My intention is not the full view rather a UIBazierPath. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: Try this -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117722/uibezierpath-with-color-gradient

Comment: The post you referred does not provide concrete solution for true gradient color. @User511

Comment: Will the third party library work for you?

Comment: I am required not to use any 3rd party lib

Comment: OK. I thought may be that will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To answer this question of yours,

> I have a UIBezierPath inside my custom UIView draw(_ rect: CGRect)
>   function. I would like to fill the path with a gradient color.

Lets say you have an oval path,

```
let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
```

To create a gradient,

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = path.bounds
gradient.colors = [UIColor.magenta.cgColor, UIColor.cyan.cgColor]
```

We need a mask layer for gradient,

```
let shapeMask = CAShapeLayer()
shapeMask.path = path.cgPath
```

Now set this `shapeLayer` as `mask` of `gradient` layer and add it to `view`'s layer as `subLayer`

```
gradient.mask = shapeMask
yourCustomView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

**Update**
Create a base layer with stroke and add before creating gradient layer.

```
let shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.path = path.cgPath
shape.lineWidth = 2.0
shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
self.view.layer.addSublayer(shape)

let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = path.bounds
gradient.colors = [UIColor.magenta.cgColor, UIColor.cyan.cgColor]

let shapeMask = CAShapeLayer()
shapeMask.path = path.cgPath
gradient.mask = shapeMask

self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. gradient works but the stroke is not shown.  `I need to fill the clip with a gradient color and then stroke the path with black color`. How can i fix this.

Comment: As I am overriding `UIView`, inside `draw()` func I assume you mean `self.layer` instead of `self.view.layer`. I follow all your updated instructions, works pretty close but  its only showing borderlines in black. No strokes in the middle of the graph is showing. @Matt

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have just added `shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor` and the problem is solved.

Comment: Can you also help on that post, http://stackoverflow.com/q/41464101/1084174

Comment: Sweet and simple. :)

Comment: For me it doesn't work without setting
`shapeMask.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
shapeMask.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeMask.lineWidth = shapeLayer.lineWidth`

Answer (score 17):

You can do this directly in Core Graphics without using `CALayer` classes. Use `bezierPath.addClip()` to set the bezier path as the clipping region. Any subsequent drawing commands will be masked to that region.

I use this wrapper function in one of my projects:

```
func drawLinearGradient(inside path:UIBezierPath, start:CGPoint, end:CGPoint, colors:[UIColor])
{
    guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    ctx.saveGState()
    defer { ctx.restoreGState() } // clean up graphics state changes when the method returns

    path.addClip() // use the path as the clipping region

    let cgColors = colors.map({ $0.cgColor })
    guard let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: cgColors as CFArray, locations: nil)
        else { return }

    ctx.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: start, end: end, options: [])
}
```

Comment: Not only is it useful, but also necessary if one starts from `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(:)` rather than a `UIView`.

Comment: I find this answer interesting, but as I tried to put it in place I wondered. What CGPoint should I put as argument? Of course I guess you're speaking about the path, but then I don't know how to get these points from it. All I generally do is playing with the CALayer's `strokeEnd`, but then I have a CGFloat ranging from 0...1, not a CGPoint. Could you help me clarify these... points?  :)

Comment: @itMaxence In this particular function, the `start` and `end` CGPoints specify how to position the color gradient (they do not affect the position of the clipping path). Also, the method here is specifically *not* using CALayer.

Comment: Indeed, not targeted to CALayer my bad! I'm still left with one question to be sure I understood correctly. The path is only used as a mask, so there is no actual way to make, say a specific race route, on a road, to then apply a CGGradient along that path? Unless you subdivide the whole path, to draw linear gradients yourself?

Comment: @itMaxence It sounds like you want a gradient _stroke_ along a path rather than a gradient _fill_. Possibly this is more relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1303855/7488171

Answer (score 3):

The other answers here don't seem to work (At least in newer iOS versions?)

Here's a working example of a bezier path being created and the stroke being a gradient stroke, adjust the CGPoints and CGColors as needed:

```
        CGPoint start = CGPointMake(300, 400);
        CGPoint end = CGPointMake(350, 400);
        CGPoint control = CGPointMake(300, 365);
        
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath new];
        [path moveToPoint:start];
        [path addQuadCurveToPoint:end controlPoint:control];
        
        CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer new];
        shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0;
        //[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
        
        CGRect gradientBounds = CGRectMake(path.bounds.origin.x-shapeLayer.lineWidth, path.bounds.origin.y-shapeLayer.lineWidth, path.bounds.size.width+shapeLayer.lineWidth*2.0, path.bounds.size.height+shapeLayer.lineWidth*2.0);
        CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer new];
        gradientLayer.frame = gradientBounds;
        gradientLayer.bounds = gradientBounds;
        gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
        gradientLayer.mask = shapeLayer;
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version of @AlbertRenshaw's (ObjC) answer, and wrapped in a UIView class.
What it displays looks spherical but on it's side.
A CGAffineTransform could be applied to rotate it 90º for a cool effect.

import UIKit

```
class SphereView : UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2)
        let radius = frame.height / 2
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, 
                                      radius: radius, 
                                      startAngle: 0, 
                                      endAngle: .pi * 2, 
                                      clockwise: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path         = circlePath.cgPath;
        shapeLayer.strokeColor  = UIColor.green.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth    = 2.0;

        let gradientBounds = CGRectMake(
            circlePath.bounds.origin.x    - shapeLayer.lineWidth,
            circlePath.bounds.origin.y    - shapeLayer.lineWidth,
            circlePath.bounds.size.width  + shapeLayer.lineWidth * 2.0,
            circlePath.bounds.size.height + shapeLayer.lineWidth * 2.0)
        
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame  = gradientBounds;
        gradientLayer.bounds = gradientBounds;
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue].map { $0.cgColor }
        gradientLayer.mask = shapeLayer;
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

Usage in a UIViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    let sphereView = SphereView()
    sphereView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(sphereView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        sphereView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        sphereView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        sphereView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
        sphereView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
    ])
}
```