# iOS - Fill Animation of a UIBezierPath from bottom

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, swift3, core-graphics

I have a `UIBezierPath` inside custom `UIView`, `draw()`. I want to fill that path, lets say a rectangle from bottom to top. How can I implement this.

From [Here](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/fun-with-cashapelayer/) I have seen using `CAShapeLayer` its possible. That is working fine with animation but filling is not happening from bottom to top on the rectangle. Please guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are asking for?

```
func zoom() {
    let startPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height-30, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 30))
    let endPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))

    let rectangleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    rectangleLayer.path = startPath.cgPath
    rectangleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(rectangleLayer)

    let zoomAnimation = CABasicAnimation()
    zoomAnimation.keyPath = "path"
    zoomAnimation.duration = 2.0
    zoomAnimation.toValue = endPath.cgPath
    zoomAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    zoomAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    rectangleLayer.add(zoomAnimation, forKey: "zoom")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. How can i implement it when endPath is not a rectangle rather a trapezium. I tried with addLines, but then filling direction is not as expected. Do u know if its possible to get a workaround. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! , it solved my problem. You are just awesome!