# Color gradient filling along a path in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I want to create custom paths with a gradient along with it, something like on the image:
[image]

How do I do that with SwiftUI?

UPD.
I know about linear, angular, radial gradients described in apple documentation. Now I use a combination of linear gradients:
[image]

But I don't know how to create a custom shape like this:
 [image]

Comment: While not SwiftUI, have you looked at the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41437581/how-to-fill-a-bezier-path-with-gradient-color

Answer (score 1):

mask modifier

```
LinearGradient(…).mask(myPath.stroke(…))
```