# How to apply gradient to sector arc for pie chart using CoreGraphics

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-graphics, pie-chart

I am new to Core Graphics. From many tutorials, I have developed a pie chart as shown in the image.
[image]

But now I want to add some gradient to its sector arc as shown in the image.

How to achieve it using Core Graphics?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a great resource for learning advanced Core Graphics stuff:
[Core Graphics Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32283/core-graphics-tutorial-lines-rectangles-and-gradients), but I'm not sure it covers radial gradients.  This question demonstrates radial gradients and you should be able to take it from there: [How can I draw a sector with radial gradient (iphone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696015/how-can-i-draw-a-sector-with-radial-gradient-iphone).

Comment: I have referred the tutorial you mentioned and all the answers of the stackoverflow. But somehow, I am not able to achieve exact effect.