# Encapsulate drawRect gradients in CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, gradient

There are dozens of excellent [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696015/how-can-i-draw-a-sector-with-radial-gradient-iphone) on here and elsewhere of how to use gradients by

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

However, I'm new to Quartz and it's likely I'm missing something. When I found [this](http://danielbeard.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/gradient-background-for-uiview-in-ios/), it seems more intelligent to create a CAGradientLayer and then add it to my view with something like:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear
{
   CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer blueGradient];
   bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
   [self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

Where the blueGradient is a separate class method (within BackgroundLayer.m) which creates the gradient, as follows:

```
+ (CAGradientLayer*) blueGradient {

    UIColor *colorOne   = [UIColor colorWithRed:(120/255.0) green:(135/255.0) blue:(150/255.0) alpha:1.0];
   UIColor *colorTwo   = [UIColor colorWithRed:(57/255.0)  green:(79/255.0)  blue:(96/255.0)  alpha:1.0];

   NSArray *colors     = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)colorOne.CGColor, colorTwo.CGColor, nil];
   NSNumber *stopOne   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
   NSNumber *stopTwo   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];

   NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stopOne, stopTwo, nil];

   CAGradientLayer *headerLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
   headerLayer.colors = colors;
   headerLayer.locations = locations;

   return headerLayer;

}
```

So here's my question. What if instead of this simple linear gradient, I want to create a radial one? How can I extend blueGradient so that it can handle two dimensional gradients? Or what if I want to add gradients on top of gradients? the drawRect function seems so limiting.

Or maybe that's just the wrong approach... then what's the wiring that I'm missing? How do I add gradients to my view(s) using drawRect? I want to be sure I'm doing it in a modular way so I can add gradient overlays, etc, as additional layers as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of iOS 7, `CAGradientLayer` can only draw a linear gradient.  It cannot draw a radial gradient.

You can either use the `drawRect:` approach, or you can draw your gradient into an image and display the image in a view or layer.  You can draw it into a `UIImage` and display it in a `UIImageView`, or you can draw it into a `CGImage` and set it as the `contents` of a `CALayer`.

Comment: Can you give an example of the code for this? Obviously it's not this, but just the line like UIImage *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer blueGradient], would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Well it looks like I'm on my own for this one... regardless, you did answer part of the question... so the points are yours.